Display screen resolution not detecting 1080p - HP probook 445 G10 ryzen 7
I have installed ubuntu on my laptop but the display resolution is stuck at  1360x768      59.98, I have updated the latest drivers but facing same issue, can someone please help me on this?
The command
cvt -r 1920 1080

returns:
1920x1080 59.93 Hz (CVT 2.07M9-R) hsync: 66.59 kHz; pclk: 138.50 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080R"  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync

Also, the command
xrandr

returns:
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm

   1360x768      59.98*+
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77 

